# align text to the right of an div container

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
div_p {
}
.img_block {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
}
.img_o {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.img_i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="img_block gwd-div-0pxe">
    <img class="img_o" src="images/scene1.jpg">
    <img class="img_i" src="images/scene2.jpg"><span style="position:absolute;        top:10px;right:10px;">100</span>

  </div>
  <div class="div_p"><p>hi hello how are you</p></div>
  <div class="img_block">
    <img class="img_o" src="images/scene2.jpg">
    <img class="img_i" src="images/scene3.jpg"><span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;">100</span>

  </div>
  <div class="div_p"><p>hi hello how are you</p></div>
  <div class="img_block">
    <img class="img_o" src="images/scene4.jpg">
    <img class="img_i" src="images/scene5.jpg"><span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;">100</span>

  </div>
  <div class="div_p"><p>hi hello how are you</p></div>
</div>
```

i need to bring the text of class `div_p` to the right of the images but currently its placed below the image by this code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the images to float left.

```
.img_block {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<div class="img_block">
    <img class="img_o" src="images/scene2.jpg">
    <img class="img_i" src="images/scene3.jpg"><span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;">100</span>
    <div class="div_p"><p>hi hello how are you</p></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.div_p p {
    float: right;
    max-width: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
}

.img_o {
    float: left;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

And use max-width to limit its width so that it would not come in the container of the text. And the text will stay there.

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/e2u4y/1/

Answer (score 0):

you should apply

```
.div_p {
float: left;
}
```

or

```
.div_p {
position: absolute;
right: 10px; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

and then style it how you want to